# Executing SSIS package with SSAS task from c#

Tags: c#, ssis, ssas

I'm trying to run ssis package from c# application, console in current case;
And in SSIS package i have simple Data flow tasks, and Analysis Service Task
And its allway Faild with sych error

"To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Analysis Services Processing Task of Integration Services or higher.
"

```
 try
        {
            var app = new Application();
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(location, null);
            pkg.EnableConfigurations = true;
            pkg.ExportConfigurationFile(@"E:\Olap\StatIntegration\Publisher.dtsConfig");
            foreach (var conn in pkg.Connections)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(conn.ConnectionString);
            }
            pkgResults = pkg.Execute();
            if (pkgResults == DTSExecResult.Failure)
            {

                foreach (var err in pkg.Errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(err.Description);
                }
           }
```

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SQL Server install media and install Integration Services. The error message is a bit buggy but that's what it means.

Comment: But i'v allready did it. I have SQL data tools for vs 2013 and SQL server Integration and Analysis service 2012. I'd run my packages throught c# from SQL server not from local file. And it Works. Thank you

Comment: @VladimirKostyrko I wonder if it was looking for Integration Services from SQL2014 to be installed. That's the version which VS2013 is tied to. But help me understand what you did. You deployed the SSIS package to SQL server (to MSDB? To SSISDB?). Can you post your updated code to benefit others?